# PHP: Popular Posts via MYSQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting

So I want to show the 5 most popular posts on my blog page (no wordpress, all html and php) by making a mysql query. The popularity is the count of comments on that post. This would be easy If my blog-entry table would contain a *comment-count*. But I´m looking for a solution without changing all my mysql tables again. So, I´ve got 2 tables:

Table **Blog**
Contains Columns: ID | Content | Date
Example Row: 1 | Hello Guys, today I went shopping | 01.01.01
Table **Comments**
Contains Columns: ID | Content | Date | Account | Reference
Example Row: 2 | Awesome Entry! | 02.01.01 | Kim | 1

Basically, every time somebody comments on a entry his Account-Name and Comment is being inserted into the *Comments* table. Additionally, there is an auto-increment ID and a Reference which contains the ID of the *Blog* Entry it belongs to (and there´s a date). The *Blog* table simply contains what it should display (except its auto-incrementing ID, which is used for the Reference Column in the Comments table).
So, what Query should I run to get the Blog-Entrys which the most comments refer to in the *Reference*-Column?

**EDIT:** I´ve tried various combinations of sum(), count() and max() never getting the expected result. Should have written this earlier.

Comment: It would be nice to see what it was that you tried in order to have resolved this yourself, which would have shown us that you did research this before posting the question. 
When you try, you also learn. If someone just gives you an answer/solution, it would have all been for nothing and I say this for the/your future. 
You can then edit your post to contain something that may have failed; even that shows an effort on your part. Remember, we're always glad to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query gets you all the blogs with the comments with higher count. I have used **limit** to limit the no of records fetched

```
SELECT b.content, b.id AS blogid, COUNT(c.id) as commentsCount
FROM blog b
JOIN comments c ON c.reference = b.id
GROUP BY b.id
HAVING commentsCount > 0
ORDER BY commentsCount desc
LIMIT 5
```

I have added the comment to each line. Please check

```
SELECT b.content, b.id AS blogid, COUNT(c.id) as commentsCount //This line you can select whatever columns you need.
     FROM blog b
    JOIN comments c ON c.reference = b.id //Joing comments by reference column
    GROUP BY b.id //group the column
    HAVING commentsCount > 0 //The blog may have or may not have comments 
    ORDER BY commentsCount desc //Used to get the highest comment count first 
    LIMIT 5 //get only 5 records if you want 10 records then replace by 10. If you want all the records then remove this line
```

Comment: Could you explain to me what that query is doing?

Comment: Okay I will. Will write a comment to the answer

Comment: @SearchingSolutions Is my answer working for you. In case if any other query please let me know

Answer (score 0):

Even though the answer from Channaveer Hakari worked perfectly fine, I found a shorter query for this:

```
SELECT * FROM `Blog` b JOIN (SELECT c.Reference, Count(*) AS cnt FROM `Comments` c GROUP BY c.Reference) d ON (d.Reference=b.ID) ORDER BY cnt DESC;
```